# Safest way to override the update method of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class TwitterEngagement < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And I would like to override `create` (and `create!`), `update` (and 
`update!`) methods of it so no one can manually entry fake data. I would like the help of someone more experienced with active record and rails so I don't mess anything up. Right now what I have is:

```
class TwitterEngagement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page

  def create
    super(metrics)
  end

  def update
    super(metrics)
  end

  private

  def metrics
    client.get_engagements(page.url)

  def client
    TwitterClient.new
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR:

```rb
class FacebookEngagement < ApplicationRecord
  def create_or_update(*args, &block)
    super(metrics)
  end
```

- Probably depends on your Rails version, but I traced the [`ActiveRecord::Persistence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html) sometime before in Rails 5, and found out that both `create` and `update` eventually calls `create_or_update`.

### Suggestion:

If ever possible, I'll just do a validation, because it kinda makes more sense because you are validating the inputs, and then probably set an *optional* [`readonly?`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Core/readonly%3F), to prevent saving of records. This will also prevent "silent failing" code / behaviour as doing `TL;DR` above would not throw an exception / populate the validation errors, if say an unsuspecting developer does: `facebook_engagement.update(someattr: 'somevalue')` as the arguments are gonna basically be ignored because it's instead calling `super(metrics)`, and would then break the principle of least surprise.

So, I'll probably do something like below:

```
class FacebookEngagement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page

  validate :attributes_should_not_be_set_manually
  before_save :set_attributes_from_facebook_engagement

  # optional
  def readonly?
    # allows `create`, prevents `update`
    persisted?
  end

  private

  def attributes_should_not_be_set_manually
    changes.keys.except('page_id').each do |attribute|
      errors.add(attribute, 'should not be set manually!')
    end
  end

  def set_attributes_from_facebook_engagement
    assign_attributes(metrics)
  end

  def metrics
    # simple memoization to prevent wasteful duplicate requests (or remove if not needed)
    @metrics ||= graph.get_object("#{page.url}?fields=engagement")
  end

  def graph
    Koala::Facebook::API.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. I should also add a guard clause `next if attribute == 'page_id'` in the block of the changes.key.each, right?

Comment: Not really. I'm using the `Page` model: `page = Page.first; page.create_facebook_engagement`

Comment: I'm actually testing all use cases. Creating directly from the `FacebookEngagement` works :thumbs_up:

Comment: Ohh I see, right `page_id` is not part of the metrics hash. So yup, you're right, you can do `next if attribute == 'page_id'` or you can also do `changes.keys.except('page_id')` :)

Comment: Awesome! My last question for you would be about updating... I should allow the update operation cause I will have a cronjob that runs every day to update the metrics of each FacebookEngagement resource. Would it be possible to overcome the error when I try to call update: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))`?

Comment: @user12212177 What line is causing this `ArgumentError`? Maybe I have a type somewhere.

Comment: When I try to update an item, for example: `page = Page.last; page.facebook_metric.update`. If I understand this correctly I need to pass a hash with the props that I want to update

Comment: @user12212177 And yes, the `readonly?` there is optional. Since you say the records are being updated every day, then no need for `readonly?` :)

Comment: @user12212177 are you using the TL:DR? or are you using the second-longer one? If you're using TL;DR, I think I have a typo. I'm updating that now.

Comment: I'm using the suggestion. Let me try again, maybe I did something wrong, one sec haha.

Comment: No, same thing. If I try to update through a page instance the `ArgumentError` will be raised

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203943/discussion-between-jay-ar-polidario-and-user12212177).

Comment: @user12212177 continuing from our chat, on second thought, since this seems to be gonna be called in a background job, I suggest raising an error instead of silently failing (just in case you'll have future validations that will invalidate these records), so use `.save!` instead of `.save` like so: `page.facebook_metric.save!` This will save headaches! :)